# custom variable => product id/quantity

Tags: php

friend wrote a little script to get the product id and product quantity of the selected item.
here it is:

```
$product_id_string = $_POST['custom'];
$product_id_string = rtrim($product_id_string, ","); 
$id_values = array();
$id_str_array = explode(",", $product_id_string);
$fullAmount = 0;
foreach ($id_str_array as $key => $value) {

$id_quantity_pair = explode("-", $value);
$product_id = $id_quantity_pair[0]; // product ID
$product_quantity = $id_quantity_pair[1]; // product quantity 
}
```

how i understood it...the product id and its quantity is read just out of the custom variable?
greetings!

Comment: What is your real question ? Are you stuck any where ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please before post anything read [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: for example: in my paypal-buy-button i have custom=123456.

Comment: how the id and quantity is get out of this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly. The custom variable is a string "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd". Explode converts this into an array (in my example 4 elements.) `foreach()` iterates them, so that everything inside it will be executed 4 times, where $value takes the values aaa, bbb and so on.

$_POST['custom'] needs to be `id-quantity,id-quantity,id-quantity`, e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="A123-4,B456-1">
```

That would mean you bought 4 times the item A123 and once the item B456.

Comment: firstly i thought the product id is read from the database...

Comment: so, what should i use for "custom" in my buynow-button, when i refer to the upper script? greetings

Comment: @bobbybo Please don´t forget to upvote and accept answers that helped you, to help people with similar problems visiting that site.